# VMWare Converter recommendations

Tags: windows-xp, vmware-converter

I have two Ghost 14 backups of my machine. One for the machine fully configured with apps after and XP install and one of the last update before i re-imaged it (it's XP, I re-image about once every six months). I recently wanted to try simply using my initial image in a virtual environment to do my testing that generally causes me to need to re-image. I used the VMWare converter to convert the Ghost images to a virtual machine to use in Virtual box but they fail to properly boot. They get stuck after the bios loads and windows begins loading. If I power down the machine and refire it it will go to the error screen in windows that asks if you would like to boot to a different mode. none selected make any difference. What are some possible errors I should look for in the conversion process or in my settings for the converter?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using vmware player instead of virtualbox?  I have not tried using VMs created with converter with virtualbox.

Comment: no i have not as that as i do not have a license for it. I use virtual box since it does not require a license and claims to support the use of vmware images. I have not seen this specific issue spelled out in the support docs for either which is why i am asking here.

Comment: VMWare player is free for non-commercial use, so you can download and try it.  http://www.vmware.com/products/player/faqs.html

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience, the problem was an invalid video driver--that is, invalid under VirtualBox, it obviously worked on the real hardware.

If you choose "Safe mode with command line" do you get any output?  Post the last 15 lines or so here.

One trick I've used before: you can download a bootable Linux CD (e.g. Knoppix), mount the ISO file as a drive under VirtualBox, and boot the VM that way.  Using Knoppix you can then edit the contents of the VMDK file as if it were a real hard drive.

I haven't done this, but you could also boot the VM off your Windows XP CD (or an ISO image of it) and do a repair install.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect to have to do a repair install on the image in this situation as you have major hardware changes between the real hardware and the virtual machine "hardware".